# Software that can control Phone from PC through bluetooth?

Tags: windows, windows-phone, bluetooth

Anyone know if there is software that can take control of the phone playback functionality through Bluetooth in the similar matter the car radio does when you pair your phone to it.

I have Nokia Lumia 520 Windows phone, when I connect it to my car, I can see currently playing song on my radio, skip to next song, pause or resume play, all through my radio without ever touching my phone.

Looking for software that can let me have same functionality from a laptop that has bluetooth.

Comment: I would split this into two sub-problems: (1) how to create a network over bluetooth (shouldn't be that difficult) (2) software that can control phone from PC over the network